# Return Multiple Values from a Single Output Parameter

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

Is there a way I can make a Stored Procedure return the whole column of a result set with one calling?

I have a stored procedure that queries for a set of users based on a reference.

Scenario:

1. user1 has client1. I call the stored procedure using user1's clientId
2. I want to get all the other userId's that are under client1 and then add them into a Sharepoint group.

Is there a way to do this?

**SP Snippet**

```
DECLARE @clientId Int,
DECLARE @userId OUTPUT

SELECT @userId = UserId FROM Clients WHERE clientName = @clientId
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's quite easy in sql server, you have to specify RETURNS TABLE clause.

```
--Transact-SQL Inline Table-Valued Function Syntax 
CREATE FUNCTION [ schema_name. ] function_name 
( [ { @parameter_name [ AS ] [ type_schema_name. ] parameter_data_type 
    [ = default ] [ READONLY ] } 
    [ ,...n ]
  ]
)
RETURNS TABLE
    [ WITH <function_option> [ ,...n ] ]
    [ AS ]
    RETURN [ ( ] select_stmt [ ) ]
[ ; ]
```

Full syntax and manual here: http://technet.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/ms186755.aspx

Oh, and if a programmable object returns value then it's called a function not a procedure. Procedures differ from functions in many ways.

Comment: Is it like a method in C#?

Comment: Procedure is a void method, and function returs a type (or a TABLE in this case)

Comment: Can I transfer the values to a DataTable in C#?

Comment: Not directly I'm afraid, but I'm no expert in CLR - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131092(v=sql.100).aspx

Answer (score 1):

You just have to write a SP like below, without any parameters , so that it returns a datatable of all UserIds for that particular client.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GetALLUserIdsForClient
        @clientId AS Int 
AS
BEGIN
SELECT UserId FROM Clients WHERE clientName = @clientId
END
```

Call above Store procedure from your C# code.This will return a data table.Your C# code can loop through and add users to group.